# Looping Card Game

Tags: java

Problem: My game won't loop through the entire "Deck".

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PlayWar{
 public static void main(String args[]){ 
  Deck theDeck; 
  Hand redHand,blackHand;
  PlayingCard tempCard, redCard,blackCard;
  int index;
  theDeck=new Deck(); 
  redHand=new Hand(Deck.MAX_CARDSPER_DECK/2); 
  blackHand=new Hand(Deck.MAX_CARDSPER_DECK/2);
  tempCard=theDeck.getNextCard(); 
 for (index=0; index<Deck.MAX_CARDSPER_DECK; index++){
      if (tempCard.getSuitValue()==PlayingCard.HEARTS||tempCard.getSuitValue()==PlayingCard.DIAMONDS){
           redHand.addCard(tempCard);}//end if
      else{
         blackHand.addCard(tempCard);}//emd else
     redHand.addCard(tempCard);
     blackHand.addCard(tempCard);}//end for 
 blackCard = blackHand.turnCard(tempCard);
 redCard = redHand.turnCard(tempCard); 
      //as long as the red and black hand getCouts don't equal zeros, playWar
 while(redHand.getCount()!=0&& blackHand.getCount()!=0){
     if (redCard.getSuitValue() > blackCard.getSuitValue()){
         System.out.println("The " +  redCard.toString() +
                    " is greater than the " + blackCard.toString()); 
         blackHand.tossFromHand(tempCard);
      }//end if

     if (redCard.getSuitValue()<blackCard.getSuitValue()){
         System.out.println("The " + blackCard.toString() +
                            " is higher than "+redCard.toString());
         redHand.tossFromHand(tempCard);                
       }//end if

     if (redCard.getSuitValue()==blackCard.getSuitValue()){
         System.out.println("TIE - Tossing both the "+blackCard.toString()+
                            "and the "+redCard.toString());
         blackHand.tossFromHand(tempCard); 
         redHand.tossFromHand(tempCard);                                       
       }//end if 
     }//end while  
     //out of while loop do if stamets that print out wich one wins or if its a tie
      if(redHand.getCount()!=0&& blackHand.getCount()==0)
         System.out.println("Black Wins!");
      if(redHand.getCount()==0&& blackHand.getCount()!=0)
         System.out.println("Red Wins!");
      if (redHand.getCount()==0&& blackHand.getCount()==0)
         System.out.println("It's a Tie");

       System.exit(0);//need this when import JOptionPane
      }//end main method
 }//end class
```

Output:

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

TIE - Tossing both the TWO of CLUBSand the TWO of CLUBS

It's a Tie

Question: Why is it only outputting the two of Clubs? Did I misplace a bracket?

Comment: You need to show your other functions like "getSuitValue()" and "getNextCard()"

Comment: Did you try step by step debugging in your favorite IDE?

Comment: Also if you are using something to randomize your cards, make sure you don't recreate the randomizer in every loop

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are never changing the value of `tempCard` in your `for` loop, thus both `redHand` and `blackHand` hold exactly the same cards, i.e. numerous references to the same initial `tempCard`.

Maybe you have to pick a new `tempCard` in each iteration of the loop?

```
for (index=0; index<Deck.MAX_CARDSPER_DECK; index++){
    tempCard=theDeck.getNextCard();  // move this line here?
```

Also, it seems very odd that you add the card at first, depending on the color, to either `redHand` or `blackHand`, and then *again* to both hands, so there are effectively three copies of each card.

---

Similarly to the first problem, you are never updating `redCard` and `blackCard` in your `while` loop; they remain the same card turned before the loop for the entire duration of the game. You have to turn new cards at the end of the `while` loop, e.g.

```
    blackCard = blackHand.turnCard(tempCard);
    redCard = redHand.turnCard(tempCard); 
} // end while
```

Also, those lines like `blackHand.tossFromHand(tempCard);` should probably read `blackHand.tossFromHand(blackCard);` (and analogously for red).

Comment: A similar problem exists in the loop playing cards from the dealt hands. redCard and blackCard are never updated. tempCard appears to be overused.